# Two OneToMany Sets to same Table in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table of users, and a table of calls between users.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="userId")
    private long userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="caller")
    Set<Call> madeCalls;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="callee")
    Set<Call> receivedCalls;

}

public class Call {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="calleeId", referencedColumnName="userId")
    User callee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="callerId", referencedColumnName="userId")
    User caller;

}
```

Details such as getters and setters and other field (ids etc) ommitted for brevity.

Each call involves one caller and one callee. Each user can have made and received many calls.

Simply put: is the above valid use of JPA, specifically hibernate?

Comment: If you have a `User` A, and want to search for all `madeCalls` then how do you think it will determine whether `A` made them, or received them? It simply has a single FK column in `Call` called `userId`. Oooh `A` was involved in this call ...

Comment: @BillyFrost my bad, forgot to change the column names. Hopefully makes more sense now when Call has two columns.

Comment: So with 2 FKs in `Call` then it is now possible to manage the data. Why not just try it?

Comment: @BillyFrost I'm in the process of doing so when I couldn't find any answers online. But I thought I'd ask in case I'm wasting my time that's all. I post my own conclusion if I find it works or not.

Comment: Off-topic but are you sure you have the correct relations? Shouldn't a call have one caller and many callee and can't a user have participated in many calls as a callee, that is a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's not a group chat, it's literal one-to-one contact. So each call involves one caller and one callee. But each user can have made many calls, and have received many calls.

Comment: Got it. Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a hibernate class without having a Primary Key. Moreover, you should use `property-based acccess` instead of `field-based access` otherwise hibernate will give you compile-time errors. Your codes should be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id // use all these annotation in  the getter method
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private long userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="caller") // use this annotation in  the getter method
    private Set<Call> madeCalls;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="callee") // use this annotation in  the getter method
    private Set<Call> receivedCalls;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="call")
public class Call {

    @Id // use all these annotation in  the getter method
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private long callId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="calleeId") // use this annotation in  the getter method
    private User callee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="callerId") // use this annotation in  the getter method
    private User caller;

}
```

[Here is a very good tutorial for hibernate and performance](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/tips-to-boost-your-hibernate-performance/).

Comment: I omitted a lot of that stuff just to keep the question as clean as possible, but you are correct.